# How to compute average number of infections in a graph?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Hi I am working on a graph problem for a research project and I am curious how other people would approach the following problem.  Apologies if this is the wrong forum for posting this.

Say you have a graph G with. N nodes and E edges between the nodes (edges are bi directional / go both ways).

I is the number of nodes which are infected, V are the number of nodes which are vulnerable, and the rest of the nodes are R (resistant).  If there is an edge between an I and V node., an infection occurs.  Any other edges result in no infection.  Even if a V node is connected to many I nodes, it only counts as one infection.

Now, among all possible ways you can label the nodes, what is the average number of infections that occurs in each possible labeling of the graph?

Answer (score 0):

We typically call this problem modelling contagion on a network, or epidemics on networks. Specifically you are trying to simulate an SIR model (read up on that).

There are several libraries on this you may want to check out:

- EoN https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.02436.pdf
- igraph
- Netpidemix
- epydemic
- EpiModel
- Graph-tool

You may also want to clarify:

- What do you mean by the 'labelling of the graph'? Are you talking about time steps? This is confusing: "what is the average number of infections that occurs in each possible labeling of the graph?"
- Are you using python or networkx or c++ ...?
- Are you saying there is a 100% chance of infection if connected to node with status I? re "If there is an edge between an I and V node., an infection occurs."